# Assigning a role to a member based on args

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm fairly new to Node.js and I'm currently working on a Discord bot. I'm trying to make my bot assign server roles based on arguments passed by the user. I'm aware that I can find the name of a specific role, and just assign them that role based on their response. 
However: my admins make and remove roles just about every week, and I can't just edit my code every week to update a list of available roles to be assigned, so I decided to make a line of code that would extract the passed argument of a user, and then find a role name while *passing args as a parameter*.  
Here's what my code looks like:

```
if (command === 'role'){


    let roleMember = message.member;
    var mentionedRole = args[0];
    let testRole = mentionedRole.toString();

    // Debug message to check if it reads my input
    message.channel.send(`TRYING! YOUR ARGS WERE: ${testRole}`);

    // Define the role
    let finalRole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === testRole);

    // Check if it reads the role successfully
    message.channel.send(`I READ: ${finalRole}`);

    // Add the role to the command author
    roleMember.addRole(top).catch(console.error);


  }
```

The thing is that when it returns what it read for `finalRole`, it gives me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muhA8.jpg). When the bot responds, it reads the role as null.  I've been wrestling with this for weeks now and I'm at my wit's end. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?  EDIT: Here's an example of what I mean:  
`!role top`  "Top" is the role's name here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're comparing the role name with `Role.toString()`. Using `Role.toString()` returns a mention, while `Role.name` is just the name of the role.
I would write it like this:

```
if (command === 'role') {
  let roleMember = message.member;
  // I'm getting the Role object directly from the message, so that I don't need to parse it later
  var mentionedRole = message.mentions.roles.first();

  // If there was no mentioned Role, or the are any kinds of problems, exit
  if (!mentionedRole) return message.channel.send(`I'm unable to use that role: ${mentionedRole}`);

  // Add the role to the command author
  roleMember.addRole(mentionedRole).then(message.channel.send("Role successfully added.")).catch(console.error);
}
```

Edit: if you want to use just the name of the role, without mentioning it, you can do it like this (assuming `args[0]` is the argument):

```
if (command === 'role') {
  if (!args[0]) return message.reply("Please add the role name.");

  let roleMember = message.member;
  // I'm using the first argument to find the role: now it's not case-sensitive, if you want it to be case-sensitive just remove the .toLowerCase()
  var mentionedRole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name.toLowerCase() == args[0].toLowerCase());

  // If there was no mentioned Role, or the are any kinds of problems, exit
  if (!mentionedRole) return message.channel.send(`I'm unable to use that role: ${args[0]}`);

  // Add the role to the command author
  roleMember.addRole(mentionedRole).then(message.channel.send("Role successfully added.")).catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: The thing is that `mentions.roles.first();` would need the person to mention that role, and thus pinging everyone with that role. How can I make it so I don't need to mention it, and I could pass the argument as a parameter.

Comment: Happy to hear that :)